# Multiple signin from same device using rails devise gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, rubygems, activeadmin

I am using *active admin* and *devise* gem in my project. However I am using token_authentication to sign in as a user from *active admin*. Whenever the sign in happens, the session for *active admin* is destroyed.
How can I do this without destroying *active admin* session? That means I want to be a user and admin at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

try incognito window in chrome,
or Private Browsing in Firefox.
or in private browsing in IE.
In this way in every window you'll have different cookies and different sessions.